# How to roll back promise execution in Promise.all() if one promise rejects

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have a situation for example

```
const promiseExecution = async ()=> {
    try{
        await Promise.all([
            promise1, // some db changes
            promise2, // send sms
            promise3, // other db changes
        ])
    }
    catch(er){
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Now, if one of the promise rejects, the other two are still resolved and the db changes occur.
I want a mechanism where I can rollback the promise execution in case any of them rejects.

One solution that came to my mind is to use `Promise.allSettled()` and handle the rollback for the ones that resolved independently.

Comment: The promises are independent of each other, and `Promise.all` doesn't have a cancel or rollback. So using `allSettled` and checking the status of each of the promises is the way to go ...

Comment: You might be able to rollback a database transaction if you were using one and have not yet committed it, but you cannot un-send an SMS.